# regex allow only select and disallow other operation aka insert drop flush

Tags: sql, regex

I need to let user to type full sql command as a string and then execute it on my db (not safe but it's only for internal use).
The thing is to disallow any insertion to database (insert, drop, flush, ect) - im not experienced in sql and i don't know what should i catch as unsupported operation

Second thing is blocking some tables aka Users (this can be done in user privileges but I can't change it)

I think about block some keywords and characters but I don't know witch one.

My actual regex looks like:

(?i)^select(?:(?!insert|drop|flush|database).)*$

Comment: If you want to disallow insertion into the database, do not give users `INSERT` permissions.

Comment: It's the best solution but i can't change permissions on this user and I can't use another one..

Comment: Depending in the details engine even select could be modifying the data (select into). So the only choice is to whitelist types of sell statements. You either provide an interface that builds a few preselected sql types or have to parse the user SQL Lin a grammar that allows only select, and reconstruct it again (so what is not understood is skipped).